# Paste to next empty column

Tags: vba, excel

I already have this code that paste to the next empty row. It works perfectly but now I have a new VBA project that i would like to do the same thing but columns instead of rows

Current Code:

```
 intLast = shtAlpha.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)
 intNext = intLast + 5 - (intLast + 1) Mod 5
 Set rngDest = shtAlpha.Cells(intNext, "C").Resize(5, 3)
```

I tried this but I got **Compile Error Method or data member not found**, It highlights

```
.Cells
```

/

```
intLast = Omega.Cells(Columns.Count, "1").End(xlRight).Column
intNext = intLast + 5 - (intLast + 5) Mod 5
Set rngDest = Omega.Cells(intNext, "A").Resize(30000, 3)
```

Comment: `Omega.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xltoLeft).Column`  will be the last occupied column in row 1

Comment: AFAIK `Cells()` needs two integers, can't use alpha characters.  So, you'd want `shtAlpha.Cells(Rows.Count,3).End(xlUp)`.  Or, if you *do* want to use letters, change it to `shtAlpha.Cells(Rows.Count,columns("C").Column)`.

Comment: "1" is not a number. It is a text string containing the ASCII character that corresponds to the visual image of the number 1. 1 is a number. "1" is a text string.

Comment: @BruceWayne - the second argument can be either a number or a column letter.

Comment: @TimWilliams - Ah, I did not realize that.  Thanks!

Comment: I used a mixture of things suggested and got it to work, Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the last column in row 1 with anything in it you should be doing

```
intLast = Omega.Cells(1,Omega.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
intNext = intLast + 5 - (intLast + 5) Mod 5
Set rngDest = Omega.Cells(1,intNext).Resize(30000, 3)
```

Let's go through the changes one at a time:

`Cells` takes two parameters. The first indicates the row the second indicates the column. You want to start on the *last column* of the *first row*. So the first parameter should be 1. The second should be the number of columns in your worksheet.

**Note** that it is generally a good practice to specify which worksheet/workbook you are working on. This helps prevent errors if there are multiple books open or the wrong worksheet is selected.

`.End` will take you to the boundary of the *region* you are in. Since you are at the last cell on the first row you are at the *far-right* of the sheet. So you have tomove to the **left** to find the last column with values in it. hence `.End(xlToLeft)`

**Note** The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839539.aspx) tells us that the parameter must be one of [these](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820880.aspx) values.

Now for your error message. You can often refer to [this handy VBA error list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj692802.aspx) for more info on what could be causing your error. I reccomend searching the error number if it is given in the error alert.

It sounds like your error is caused because `Omega` is not the correct type. VBA is telling you that you are trying to access a member called `Cells` but it cannot find it in the object. I suggest adding `Omega` to the watch and look at its members when the error occurs. With a little debugging you should be able to find the source of the problem!

Hopefully this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

The `Range()` function accepts only cell references as text Strings e.g. `Range("A1")`.

The `Cells()` function accepts only numeric row/column references e.g. `Cells(1, 1)`.

In this case, you'd need to change

```
 intLast = shtAlpha.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)
```

to

```
 intLast = shtAlpha.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)
```

Comment: Actually I believe you can use a string as the index for the column.